# listview with checkboxes and without

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I want to use a listview with checkboxes and some other options with out checkboxes

So my question is :
How can I implement the checkboxes for just some listview-entries ?

Model.java file:

```
public class Model {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

rowbuttonlayout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30px" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" >
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

InteractiveArrayAdapter.java file:

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

mylist.java file:

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
                getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));
        // Initially select one of the items
        list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        return list;
    }

    private Model get(String s) {
        return new Model(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: cb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); for your checkboxes in the getView() when needed... say on tag or on position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getView` and after this line

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
```

you have to decide whether to show your checkbox or not depending on your model (list var in your case). Then just do `holder.checkbox.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );` when you don't want to show the checkbox or `holder.checkbox.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );` when you do.

Comment: how can I disable only one checkbox ?

Comment: You can hide as many checkboxs as you want. If you just want to hide one, set its visibility to INVISIBLE for that item.

Comment: I am not able to get the checkbox id so when I call holder.checkbox.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE ); every ckeckbox is hided

Comment: I see. You are getting the id correctly, you just have to decide which item shows the checkbox and which don't. Try this piece of code: (ooops!, code in next comment)

Comment: if( ((String)list.get(position)).equals("Linux") ){ holder.checkbox.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE ) }else{ holder.checkbox.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE ); };

Comment: and how can I ad an onclick listener to the items without the checkboxes ?

Comment: Have a look at onItemClick: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Checkboxes visiblity when needed.

cb.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE);

cb.setVisiblity(VIEW.VISIBLE)

Comment: how can I disable only one checkbox ?